# How stop Android Studio from collapsing (closing) all the directories in "Project Files" pane?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Every time I run gradle/build, the project files pane refreshes and closes every directory so I only see:

- app
- MyApp

How can I keep them open?

Comment: I have the exact same question.  I'm coming from Eclipse, where I kept the file browser open all the time.  With Android Studio, every time I build it collapses the entire Project Files -- very annoying.  Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Obviously a bug. I don't see why any of the views should collapse when building the app. And, yes, this old issue seems to have been reintroduced in AS 2.2. Terribly annoying.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I just got an answer to the same question -- the solution is to use the "Project" view and not the "Project Files" view!

The Project view will not collapse when rebuilding.

[image]

See this question also:
[Running a build collapses all folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129169/android-studio-running-a-build-collapses-all-the-folders-in-the-project-browse)

Comment: Any solution for those who who Android view?

Comment: I use the "Android" view as well, and Android Studio started collapsing all the folders after recent update. It's annoying. I'm on AS 2.2.

Answer (score 13):

I solve this problem selecting AutoScroll from Source on android (or project) view option.

[image]

Comment: Don't understand why this was downvoted. At least now (for AS 2.2) this definitely improves the situation. Upvote from me.

Comment: This is a big help. Great find. As long as you have some java file open already it will pop open the main project-specific tree.

Comment: This is what worked for me. I'm using Android Studio 2.3.2. Thanks.