# Android Studio - running a build collapses all the folders in the Project browser?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been developing on Eclipse for years and have just started a new project on Android Studio.

I'm noticing that every time I run a build, Android Studio **collapses ALL the folders** in the Project Files browser, such that they need to be re-expanded to get back to where I want them.

This is what I'm left with:

> -> app
>
> -> MyApplicationName

For me, this is incredibly annoying and unnecessarily disruptive to the development process.  Yet, I don't see a solution online, so I'm suspecting I'm missing something obvious...

Is there a way to prevent Studio from auto-collapsing the Project Files browser?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I think you want to use the "Project" view, and not the "Project Files" view. I had this problem when I first switched from Eclipse to Android Studio and found it was because I'd set the file browser (top left) to look at Project files and not Project. The normal Project view does much the same thing and doesn't collapse when running tests.

Comment: That was the problem!!  I knew it had to be something simple, otherwise everyone would have been complaining.  Thank you!

Comment: Why it collapses all files even though 'Android' is selected from top left corner? It didn't use to do so before!

Comment: Any solution for those who who Android view?

Comment: Seems to work.  So what are the difference between "Project" and "Project Files" and why would those difference lead to this behavior?  Any explanation?

Comment: @Apurva - I've had problems with Android view collapsing when running. The only thing I've found thus far is to enable Autoscroll from Source in the Project tab settings as shown in the following image [link](http://imgur.com/a/ZaIuT). This will expand the tree to show the file you are currently viewing in editor, which is better than nothing.

Comment: @WallyHale only your solution worked for me as it was doing it every pane, Android, Project

Answer (score -5):

This is not default behavior. It does not happen in my Android Studio. Which Android studio are you using?

The only time when something like this should happen is when there are bugs in the project and Android STudio navigates to each bug (opens a file containing the bug). I cannot remember of any other.

Also, if you never before used Android Studio, then just double check if you maybe have some old `.AndroidStudio` folder which contains settings data. Maybe in the past you installed some old version which has this feature turned on or you accidentally turned it on and these changes were now imported. I see no other logical explanation for this.

Comment: I don't have a .AndroidStudio folder in my home directory (would it be somewhere else?), but my project is in fact getting "warnings" due to deprecated syntax that's being used.  Would these warnings cause this behavior?

Comment: It could. When there is an error or errors, the folder will collapse and it will navigate you to the file with bug in the file tree. Try fixing those errors and see the result. I am confident the "bug" will be gone

Comment: The solution was to use the "Project" view and not the "Project Files" view, as detailed by Mike Hogg.  But thank you. )

Comment: Telling the OP that you don't have the issue isn't really helpful.  Clearly there IS a logical explanation.

Comment: Please see the answer above from MikeH. Android Studio collapses all project folders when you run the project (I am on version 2.3.3). In order to view your project structure (similar to Eclipse default behavior) use the Project View from the far left and Select Android Sub view on the top.