# Android Studio collapses the project view when restarting, how do I disable this behavior?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm having trouble finding the setting that prevents AS from collapse my project view structure each time I restart AS.

If I exit AS and my Project view is looking as so:

[image: Uncollapsed]

And when AS is restarted, this is what's showing in my Project view:

[image: collpased]

All I could find that was related to this was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129169/android-studio-running-a-build-collapses-all-the-folders-in-the-project-browse) question, but I'm not having the same problem with the view being collapsed when I build my project.

Is there any setting that let saves the current Project view, so that the view as shown in the first image is shown when I open AS again?

Comment: Maybe it's a bug in the version. I face the same issue, it didn't use happen before